# R non-printable separator

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read a csv file that uses special characters as separator and quote. The delimiter is ascii character 20, and the quote character is ascii 254.

How can I pass these two parameters into the read.csv function?

```
MyData <- read.csv(file="c:/TheDataIWantToReadIn.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use `rawToChar` to save the values you need in an object then pass them to the `read.table` `sep` and `quote` arguments (`read.csv` will work too but the naming is not helpful for readability).

```
vals <- c(20, 254)
mode(vals) <- "raw"
vals <- c(rawToChar(vals[1]), rawToChar(vals[2]))

# write some example data
data <- mtcars[1:5, ]
for(i in names(data)){data[ ,i] <- paste0(vals[2], data[ , i], vals[2])}
write.table(data, "test.txt", quote = FALSE, sep = vals[1], row.names = FALSE)

# read data
read.table("test.txt", sep = vals[1], quote = vals[2], header = TRUE)
```

The data written to file looks like this:

```
mpgcyldisphpdratwtqsecvsamgearcarb
þ21þþ6þþ160þþ110þþ3.9þþ2.62þþ16.46þþ0þþ1þþ4þþ4þ
þ21þþ6þþ160þþ110þþ3.9þþ2.875þþ17.02þþ0þþ1þþ4þþ4þ
þ22.8þþ4þþ108þþ93þþ3.85þþ2.32þþ18.61þþ1þþ1þþ4þþ1þ
þ21.4þþ6þþ258þþ110þþ3.08þþ3.215þþ19.44þþ1þþ0þþ3þþ1þ
þ18.7þþ8þþ360þþ175þþ3.15þþ3.44þþ17.02þþ0þþ0þþ3þþ2þ
```

And when read back in it looks like this:

```
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! That got me half ways there because my file was encoded in UTF-8. I modified you code
write.table(data, "test.txt", quote = FALSE, sep = vals[1], row.names = FALSE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
read.table("test.txt", sep = vals[1], quote = vals[2], header = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")
It has no problem writing, but the quote is not recognized when reading.